# Poedit : "Source code not available error" for Html/Html5 files

Tags: php, gettext, po, poedit, xgettext

I get a "Source code not available error"  whenever i try to extract from source an Html5 source file.

Note that when i change its extention to .php or try to extract from any php file, the existing source code is extracted without errors. Unfortunately, that option is not viable.

Here is the Catalogue properties where the source file paths are configured :

[image: Capture]

This is the resulting error when trying to extract the source code so that it can be translated in poedit:

[image: Capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following steps:

- First, Open Poedit and go to File->preferences

[image: step 1]

- Second, Click on the Extractors Tab and add a custom extractor with
  the plus sign on the bottom. Mine is already created as you see in
  the picture.

[image: step 2]

- Finally add the following values to the relevant fields:

Field 1 = PHP

Field 2 = ‪*.php;*.html;*.html5

Field 3 = xgettext --language=PHP --add-comments=TRANSLATORS: --force-po -o %o %C %K %F

Field 5 = ‪%f

[image: step 3]

And that is it. Hopefully you can now add your html or html5 file paths in the catalogue properties and enjoy the Poedit extraction features without any problem.